# "find: missing argument to -exec" when executing a shell script

Tags: shell

I am trying to execute a shell script which has the following within it:

```
find /hana/shared/directory -type d -mtime +2 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

This works on other [SUSE Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SUSE_Linux) servers but on one. It keeps returning the following:

> find: missing argument to -exec

If, however, I place the same syntax into a terminal and run it manually, it runs without issue.

I can see this is a common issue, but I believe I have tried many of the suggestions to no avail and I'm a bit stuck now.

Comment: exec must be terminated. Try `;` -> `\;` (or `\+`) so that the shell does not treat `;` as its command separator.  See: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html#tag_20_47_16

Comment: btw, performing a recursive `rm` as root from the filesystem root is a good way to lose all your data. You should probably get someone more experienced at your workplace to audit your script.

Comment: Although in this case it is unclear what your `find` command is intended to do: `-type d` only matches directories and `rm -f` never deletes directories, so it is useless

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to view and reply. The original syntax on this thread should have been as follows, it doesn't look to have pasted across properly: 
find /<path>/ -type d -mtime +2 -exec rm -rf {} \;

Comment: check for dos line ending on that command on the server that doesn't work

Comment: use three backquotes before and afer code blocks to format properly

Comment: Just wanted to add some feedback and give thanks to your replies. In this instance for me, it was to do with the file format. Having created this copied file anew using cat > filename.sh, this work :-) Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Very carefully read [find(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html), [proc(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html), and the [GNU Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) documentation.

You might want to run (**this is dangerous**; see below):

```
find  / -type d mtime +2 -exec /bin/rm -f '{}' \;
```

(use at least `-ok` instead of `-exec`)

And you probably want to clean just your `$HOME`.

But you should **avoid removing files** from `/proc/`, `/sys/`, `/dev/`, `/lib/`, `/usr/`, `/bin/`, and `/sbin/`. See [hier(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/hier.7.html) and [environ(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html).